# File permissions for a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, file-permissions, chmod

I have the following directory structure:

> var/www/example.com/public_html/index.html
>   var/www/example.com/public_html/images/example.jpg
>   var/www/example.com/public_html/javascript/example.js

I ran the following file and directory permissions command:

```
chmod -R 755 var/www/example.com/public_html
```

So, all of the above files have `755` permissions, i.e. `-rwxr-xr-x` (I've confirmed this via FileZilla).

From my browser I can navigate to `index.html` and to `example.jpg`. However, when I navigate to `example.js` , I get a 404 error).

The way I discovered this was that my `index.html` wasn't executing javascript. So `index.html` can't see `example.js` either.

What could be causing this?

Update: On localhost, index.html executes the javascript file fine. All this is happening on the remote server.

[SOLVED] -- after following this comment below, [File permissions for a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843584/file-permissions-for-javascript-file-solved#comment45956633_28843584) it still didn't work. I think the server wasn't updating / refreshing properly for some reason. So I then changed the name of the javascript folder to js, and updated index.html accordingly, and then miraculously everything worked.

Comment: A `404` error is a `File Not Found`  error. Wrong permissions normally should be a `403`  or something else but not a `404`. As of that you should check that you really don't have a typo, and look into the log file of your webserver for more details.

Comment: @t.niese good point. The file is there, and I'm getting a 404.

Comment: Show the html part linking to the js file. I bet 10 on a leading slash.

Comment: @Sebas LOL .. nope, no leading slash " <script src="javascript/example.js"></script> " .. I just updated the question to say that it's all working fine on Localhost -- but not working on the remote server.

Comment: For some reason is the MIME type for `application/javascript` not on your server?

Comment: Can you double check and navigate to `www.example.com/javascript/example.js` ?

Comment: If directly accessing  `www.example.com/javascript/example.js` in your browser really leads to a `404` error then the only - at least somehow - comprehensible reason would be that you added the `x` flag to the file.

Comment: @Sebas No, I can't navigate to `www.example.com/javascript/example.js` ... 404 error.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, the javascript file does have the x flag for user and group and public... I removed it for the public, and tried again to go to `www.example.com/javascript/example.js` , but still get a 404.

Comment: `chmod gou-x javascript/example.js`

Comment: @user1883050 files should have only the `x` flag if they are e**x**ecutables/application but normal files as `html`, `js`, `css` never should have the `x` flag. But folders on the other hand should always have the `x` flag to be e**x**plorable. But this might not be the reason for your problem at all, just a _desperate_ assumption ;)

Comment: @t.niese I think you're on the right track. I just uploaded the `example.js` file to the `var/www/example.com/public_html` folder, and it has the permissions `-rw-r--r--` and I can read it fine by navigating to `www.example.com/example.js`. How can I reset everything so that the folders have the x, but the files do not have the x? I.e., what chmod commands do I need?

Comment: The path you're trying to access from the html file is `./javascript/example.js`, but you are copying the file to `./example.js`. I don't understand this part, please clarify.

Comment: @Sebas Here's the simple problem: I can see `index.html` when I go to `example.com`. I can see `example.jpg` when I go to `example.com/images/example.jpg`. However, when I go to `example.com/javascript/example.js` I get a 404. Even though all the files have the same permissions (now), i.e., `-rw-r--r--` , and all the directories have the same permissions (now), i.e. `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: A most peculiar development: When I change the name of the `javascript` directory to something else, the `example.js` file becomes visible via the browser...

Comment: @user1883050 but did you copy the js file in the javascript folder? Your previous message is confusing in this respect. Quote: 'I just uploaded the example.js file to the var/www/example.com/public_html'

Comment: @Sebas It's working now, after I changed the name of the javascript folder to js , and changed the address from javascript/example.js to js/example.js in index.html

Comment: good to hear! Good luck

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following this comment: [File permissions for a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843584/file-permissions-for-javascript-file-solved#comment45956633_28843584) it still didn't work. I think the server wasn't updating / refreshing properly for some reason. So I then changed the name of the javascript folder to js, and updated index.html accordingly, and then miraculously everything worked.

(I'll mark this as the correct answer when StackOverflow lets me.)